# Returned string that looks like an array from database - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The database returns me a string like so :

```
"date_approved"=>"2015-01-01T10:19:44+00:00", "date_realized"=>"2015-01-01T10:31:11+00:00", "date_tn_approved"=>"2015-01-01T10:09:40+00:00"
```

What's the best to convert this into an array so I can use this data easily?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a nice way is to make that string into a JSON format string, by replacing '=>' with ':', then apply json_decode().

```
$str = '"date_approved"=>"2015-01-01T10:19:44+00:00", "date_realized"=>"2015-01-01T10:31:11+00:00", "date_tn_approved"=>"2015-01-01T10:09:40+00:00"';
$str = '{'. str_replace('=>', ':', $str). '}';
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

// Test
var_export($arr);
//array ('date_approved'=>'2015-01-01T10:19:44+00:00', 'date_realized'=>'2015-01-01T10:31:11+00:00', 'date_tn_approved'=>'2015-01-01T10:09:40+00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is the output of the `var_export` function. The opposite of it is `eval` but it is considered a bad practice in terms of security so you can try:

```
$data = '"date_approved"=>"2015-01-01T10:19:44+00:00", "date_realized"=>"2015-01-01T10:31:11+00:00", "date_tn_approved"=>"2015-01-01T10:09:40+00:00"';
$result = array();
$items = explode(',', $data);

foreach($items as $item) {
    $item_data = explode('=>', $item);
    $result[trim($item_data[0], '"')] = trim($item_data[1], '"');
}
```

Finally in `$result` you will have an array with the parsed data for this specific data row.

Comment: `eval` is not bad practice though you may consider it as such. Some use it badly but it is there to run PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

It's untrusted data coming from the database but this should do it:

```
eval("\$array = array($string);");
print_r($array);
```

You could also try this but just like the other answers, it won't work with all data (if it contains the >," in the data):

```
$string = str_replace(array(',','"','>'), array('&','',''), $string);
parse_str($string, $array);
print_r($array);
```